# How can I add JsonTypeInfo (annotation) on java.util.ArrayList

Tags: object, serialization, jersey, jackson

My POJO:

```
public class Album{

    private String title;  
    private Object tracks; // I can not change the type, beyond my control.. 

    /** setter **/
    ....
    /** getter **/
    ....
}

public class Track{

    private String title;  
    private String singer;  

    /** setter **/
    ....
    /** getter **/
    ....
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Album album = new Album ();
    album.setTitle("Thriller");
    Track track = new Track();
    track.setTitle("Beat It");
    track.setSinger("M.J");
    List<Track> trackLst = new ArrayList<Track>();
    trackLst.add(track);
    Album.setTracks(trackLst);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT, As.PROPERTY);
    m.writeValue(System.out, album);
}
    /** console printed **/
    {
        "title": "Thriller";
        "tracks":[
            "java.util.ArrayList",
            [
                {
                    "@class":"com.hs.Track",
                    "title":"Beat It",
                    "singer":"M.J"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
```

As you can see, tracks serialized to a jsonArray, one element is the type(ArrayList), the other is the real jsonArray. Is there any solution that just keep the real jsonArray? like this:

```
{
        "title": "Thriller";
        "tracks":
            [
                {
                    "@class":"com.hs.Track",
                    "title":"Beat It",
                    "singer":"M.J"
                }
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is type declaration `private Object tracks`, which causes property to match definition and force use of type information for the list as well. If it was declared as `List<?>`, this would not occur.

One thing you may be able to do is to use "mix-in annotations", to associate annotation like:

```
public class MixIn {
  @JsonDeserialize(as=List.class)
  @JsonSerialize(as=List.class)
  private Object tracks;
}
```

and register mix-in to apply to class `Album`. This should indicate that intended type is `List`, and avoid inclusion of type information

Comment: Thanks, but tracks is not always a List, it can be a regular pojo(like a Track), any tips?

Comment: Change your JSON? I don't see the point of union types like "List or POJO" for languages like Java; they are cumbersome to handle from typing perspective. Or, if you must, write a custom deserializer.

Comment: Thanks a lot~ I think I must write a deserializer.